# How to insert a menu when i click in a item on the contextual action bar

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin Android in my apllication. I created RecyclerView, and I created a contextual action bar in it. I wonder how can I show a menu when someone clicks on an item on the contextual action bar like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQSM0.png

my contextual action bar code:

```
 public class MyActionMode : Java.Lang.Object, ActionMode.ICallback
    {
        private RecyclerViewHolder holder;
        private Context mContext;
        private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
        private int currentPosition;
        public MyActionMode(Context context) : this(context, null, 0)
        {

        }

        public MyActionMode(Context context, RecyclerView.Adapter adapter, int position)
        {
            mContext = context;
            mAdapter = adapter;
            currentPosition = position;
        }

        public bool OnActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, IMenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
                case Resource.Id.itemOneId:

                    // do Delete
                    // mAdapter.RemoveAt(currentPosition);
                    //mAdapter.FinishActionMode();
                    return true;
                case Resource.Id.itemTwoId:
                    // do Update
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        public bool OnCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
        {
            mode.MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.ContextualMenu, menu);

            return true;
        }

        public void OnDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
        {
            mode.Dispose();
        }

        public bool OnPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You mean when you click RecyclerView item, display contextual action bar, you click one action bar, want to popup menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find you post another thread:

[Popup Menu on Contextual Action Bar its not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57398589/popup-menu-on-contextual-action-bar-its-not-working)

I have workaround you can take a look:

Firstly, you need to change your Contextualmenu, change item actionviewclass as android.widget.Button.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/itemOneId"

    android:title="Delete"/>
<item android:id="@+id/itemTwoId"
    android:title="Update"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Button"
    />
```

Secondly, fire this button click event in OnCreateActionMode

```
 public bool OnCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
    {
        mode.MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.ContextualMenu, menu);
        button =(Button)menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.itemTwoId).ActionView;
        button.Background = null;
        button.Text = "UPDATE";
        button.Click += delegate {
            PopupMenu menu1 = new PopupMenu(mContext, button);
            menu1.Inflate(Resource.Menu.popup_menu);
            menu1.Show();
        };
        return true;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: One Last Quetion, i inserted a icon on my popup menu xml and its not showing the  icon on screen and the button doenst accept backgroud image, do you know how can i insert a icon on the button ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this Article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-android-custom-action-bar-menu-and-popup-menu-creation/) out which does the same thing with a pop-up menu in Xamarin.Android

It's easy, first, you create a menu item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">  
<!--///showAsAction="always" ///-->  
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="Share" showAsAction="always" />  
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings1" android:title="Bluetooth" showAsAction="always" />  
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings2" android:title="Exit" showAsAction="always" />  
<!--/android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/-->  
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings3" android:title="Share" android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />  
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings4" android:title="Bluetooth" android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />   
</menu>
```

Then override the `OnCreateOptionsMenu`in your activity

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)  
{  
   MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.option_menu, menu);  
   return true;  
}
```

Check the article out for a detailed answer

Comment: case Resource.Id.itemOneId:
                        Android.Support.V7.Widget.PopupMenu menu = new Android.Support.V7.Widget.PopupMenu(this, Action_Bar_Menu);
                        menu.Inflate(Resource.Menu.Action_Bar_Menu);
                        menu.Show();

Comment: Did you follow the blog properly? Because we do not need that pop-up button part in your case

Comment: the example uses a button i am using the contextual action bar buttons

Comment: Yes the example also uses toolbar button and you might wanna use the appcompat toolbar rather then an actionbar https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/Supportv7/AppCompat/Toolbar/